# Selenium Maven - Project suddenly stopped recognizing imports

Tags: java, selenium, maven, visual-studio-code, selenium-webdriver

As of yesterday, my simple project was working fine until I added WebDriverWait and ExpectedConditions to my code. I was able to invoke the browser and navigate to URLs fine, however as of today everything stopped working. I'm now getting "The import org.openqa cannot be resolved" as well as "WebDriver, WebDriverWait, WebElement cannot be resolved to a type"

**My Code**

```
package mavensample;

import.java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit; //This is the only import that doesn't get an error 
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class mavensample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriverpath";
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, Timeunit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, Timeunit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://initialLink.net/");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='https://censoredlink.net/']"));
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(“a[href=‘https://censoredlink.net/‘]”)));
}}
```

I have the needed dependencies installed thru Maven, and nothing that I know of has changed since yesterday in that regard.
Any help is much appreciated

Comment: It's possible your local maven repo is messed up in some way, try `mvn clean install -U` this will force an update of all local dependencies

Comment: I just tried that, I got an error saying: "Compilation failure - cannot find symbol: class ChromeDriver location: package org.openqa.selenium - It's strange because the one import I have that works is import.io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.managers.ChromeDriverManagers

Comment: Try clearing the workspace with the command and reopen the project. **Ctrl+Shift+P** --> `Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace`.

Comment: can you add your pom dependencies to the question?